# Send mail on hosting in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I trying to send an email in cakephp3.
My config:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'username' => 'aaa@gmail.com',
            'password' => '*************',
            'className' => 'Smtp'
        ],
    ],
```

My code send mail:

```
$email = new Email('default');
$email->from(['aaa@gmail.com' => 'My Site'])
      ->to('bbb@gmail.com')
      ->subject('About')
      ->send('My message');
```

It hasn't display any error and i didn't receive any email from my mail. Can everyone help me.
Thanks very much.

Comment: not sure, but shouldn't you use EmailTransport() instead of Email?

Comment: tried using `EmailTransport('default')`?